# Design notification structure for API in C#

Tags: c#, api

I am new in designing API class library in C#. I want to build a class library which will be used by many clients. The clients will be referencing this DLL.

**My specific scenario:** Say for example there is a domain model class available in the API. The clients will query the API and get the list of these domain model classes. Now, on the basic of some condition and data, the clients will evaluate the expressions defined in the domain model class.

Here, whenever this evaluation happens, I want to log the data and the result into the database.

**What have I tried:** One solution, here, is that the client call the logging method directly on the API class. However, I don't want the client to know what all is happening on the API side. There should be Separation of Concerns and Single responsibility.

Another solution tried is Define few properties in the domain model class and the client will set these properties when the expressions are evaluated. On the domain model class side, I have defined a static event which is fired when these properties are changed. The main API class will be listening to the changes in these properties and will be executing the required actions.

**Question:** Here, I wanted to know is there any another suggested methodology or best practice to achieve this ?

I will appreciate your time and guidance. Thank you.

Here, is the code that I have tried.

**Domain class**

```
public class DomainClass
{
    private bool isTrue;

    public List<Expression> Expressions { get; set; }

    public bool IsTrue
    {
        get
        {
            return isTrue;
        }
        set
        {
            isTrue= value;              
            OnPropertyChanged("isTrue");
        }
    }

    #region Events
    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

**Expression class**

```
public class Expression
{   
    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    public string Operator { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**API class**

```
public class APIClass
{        
    public APIClass()
    {
       DomainClass.PropertyChanged += DomainClass_PropertyChanged;
    }

    void DomainClass_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Call required method.
    }

    public List<DomainClass> GetDomainClass()
    {
        // Methods returns list of domain classes
    }

    public void LogDetails (DomainClass dmClass)
    {
        // Perform the required logic.
    }
}
```

**Client Side**

```
public void ProcessDomainClasses()
    {
        APIClass api = new APIClass()
        List<DomainClass> myDomainClasses = api.GetDomainClass();

        for (int dIndex = 0; dIndex < myDomainClasses.Count; dIndex++)
        {
           // Logic to evaluate the list of expressions in the domain class based on the data the client is having.

           // So, the client will check the expression: fieldName [operator] value is true or not
            myDomainClasses[dIndex].IsTrue = true;
        }
    }
```

Let me know in case you need any more information. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Can you post some small and complete sample of what this api and client code look like. And am not sure what you mean by *clients will evaluate the expressions defined in the domain model*. So posting code will be better.

Comment: Hello Sriram, I have added the required code. Thanks.

Comment: Looks good, So in `DomainClass_PropertyChanged` method you will call `LogDetails(DomainClass)`  is it? if not post some code to clarify what `DomainClass_PropertyChanged` method does

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Will be calling the LogDetails(DomainClass) method from DomainClass_PropertyChanged method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static events looks crappy for me(atleast in this scenario). I'd do it with interface say `ILogDetails` (give proper name)

```
public interface ILogDetails
{
    void LogDetails(DomainClass dmClass);
}
```

Implement in `ApiClass` or some other class.

```
public class APIClass : ILogDetails
{
    public APIClass()
    {

    }

    public List<DomainClass> GetDomainClass()
    {
        return new List<DomainClass>()
        {
            new DomainClass(this)//Pass ILogDetails implementation
            ...
        };
    }

    public void LogDetails(DomainClass dmClass)
    {
        // Perform the required logic.
    }
}

public class DomainClass
{
    private bool isTrue;
    private ILogDetails logDetails;

    //Make constructor internal to prevent client knowing this
    internal DomainClass(ILogDetails logDetails)
    {
        this.logDetails = logDetails;
    }

    public List<Expression> Expressions { get; set; }

    public bool IsTrue
    {
        get
        {
            return isTrue;
        }
        set
        {
            isTrue = value;
            logDetails.LogDetails(this);//Call the LogDetails method
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the your time. Use of interface looks good. So, Apart from calling the APIClass when the property is Set, Are there any other best practices for notifying the APIClass from client. I thought of eventing so that the domain class does not have any weak or strong references to APIClass.

Comment: I have read about the PRISM Event Aggregator as well. I will be analyzing how that can be helpful. So, any inputs on whether it is good idea in this scenario.

Comment: No, Eventing will have the strong reference in it. It will prevent garbage collection. Technically event is a delegate, It holds the reference to the api class via [Delegate.Target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.target%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. Thing is that it abstracts the implementation details.

Comment: @DareToExplore Yes, event aggregator is a good option.. It will work with `WeakReference` to there is no strong reference there and hence api class can be garbage collected.

Comment: Ok. Got the point about events. I will prepare a similar POC using PRISM Event Aggregator. Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: Another point that I was thinking about is, the client will have to instantiate the APIClass whenever they want to load the domain classes. So, Is it a good idea to implement APIClass as Singleton. I have read that static/singleton classes remain in memory until the AppDomain is present. So, it can lead to memory leaks, right ?

Comment: If your API class makes sense to be singleton, it can be singleton. Otherwise no. There is no straight forward answer for this question. Answer will be it depends. It is not that singleton will cause memory leak. Poorly written singleton does. For example a singleton with event `SomethingChanged`, and many classes subscribed to `SomethingChanged` and never unsubscribed from it. Which is a leak, it is not the fault of singleton, it is fault of the other classes(Strictly speaking: The developer's fault)

Comment: Ok, Sriram. Thanks for your time and effort. I appreciate your guidance.